# Convert a dynamic date column from a dynamic dataframe as a factor

Tags: r, for-loop, assign

I am creating dynamically 3 dataframes through a loop to calculate the variable `Nb_Active_Accounts` on 3 levels of granularity: daily/weekly/monthly; and I am trying to convert the dynamic date column as factor in a dynamic way.
If I had only a simple weekly level dataframe, the dataframe would be named **Active_Accounts_Weekly** and would look like below:
[image]

and to convert the Week_Date from a **date** to a **factor** I would only have to do this:

```
Active_Accounts_Weekly$Week_Date <- as.factor(Active_Accounts_Weekly$Week_Date)
```

But since I am creating dynamically 3 different dataframes by using functions like `get()` and `assign()` in a loop, I am trying to convert respectively the column Day_Date/Week_Date/Month_Date to a factor.
The dynamic dataframe representation looks like this: `get( paste0("Active_Accounts_", date_granularity$var_name[i] )  )` where `var_name` is respectively equal to `"Daily"`/`"Weekly"`/`"Monthly"`

What is the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We could use `mget` to get all the data into a `list` and then loop over the `list` with `lapply` and `transform` and keep the data in a `list`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(paste0("Active_Accounts_", date_granularity$var_name)), 
       transform, Week_Date = factor(Week_Date))
```